# Libgdx unable to enter input in TextFields

Tags: libgdx, input, text, ui-design

Hello I am trying to make login screen for my game, I use TextField's.

**1.** I am not satisfied with how they look I want it to look like [this](http://mcdn3.angrybirdsnest.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Angry-Birds-Heikki-Login-Screen-340x226.jpg) but simpler - basically to have a white field next to the name of the field.

**2.** When I run the game it shows just 2 labels, and I can't edit them or anything.

**3.** Here is my code:

```
public class FirstTime implements Screen {
private Stage stage;
private UVeggFruit uVeggFruit;
private Music music;
private MenuStage menuStage;
private TextField.TextFieldStyle textFieldStyle;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private float densityT = 60 * Gdx.graphics.getDensity();
private BitmapFont bitmapFont;


public FirstTime(UVeggFruit uVeggFruit,Music music){
    this.uVeggFruit = uVeggFruit;
    this.music = music;
}



@Override
public void show() {
    stage = new Stage();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    Viewport vp = new StretchViewport(1280, 720, camera);
    stage = new Stage(vp);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    ButtonClickListener buttonClickListener = new ButtonClickListener();
    SceneLoader sc = new SceneLoader();
    CompositeItemVO sceneComposites = new CompositeItemVO(sc.loadScene("Login").composite);
    CompositeActor UI = new CompositeActor(sceneComposites, sc.getRm());
    music.setLooping(true);
    music.play();
    stage.addActor(UI);
    UI.getItem("regisbutton").addListener(buttonClickListener);
    UI.getItem("loginbutton").addListener(buttonClickListener);
    FreeTypeFontGenerator FTFG = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("Karmakooma.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter FTFP = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    FTFP.color = Color.WHITE;
    FTFP.size = Math.round(densityT);
    bitmapFont = FTFG.generateFont(FTFP);
    FTFG.dispose();
    textFieldStyle = new TextField.TextFieldStyle();
    textFieldStyle.font = bitmapFont;
    textFieldStyle.fontColor = Color.WHITE;
    TextField username = new TextField("Username",textFieldStyle);
    TextField password = new TextField("Password",textFieldStyle);
    password.setPosition(400, 400);
    username.setPosition(400, 500);
    stage.addActor(username);
    stage.addActor(password);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    camera.update();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    bitmapFont.dispose();
    music.dispose();

    }
 }
```

I will be happy if you can answer both of my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you can't edit them? I believe that the default background color for a TextField is white and it looks like you are setting your font color to white as well. Since the TextFieldStyle.fontColor is also white, I believe that it will have a white cursor.

As for customizing the look of your text fields, rather than creating a TextFieldStyle in code, I would suggest looking into Libgdx's skins. They are kind of like a CSS file for libgdx elements. [Here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin) is the wiki page for skins.

The background parameter of the TextFieldStyle class is a drawable so you should be able to achieve the look you want with a ninepatch drawable.

Comment: Yes I am sure I can't, and no the textfield is not white, only the text is white, but I will try with skins, sinde textfieldstyle does not work for me